# crear una row en view laravel como resultado de una consulta del controller

Tags: php, laravel

buenas tardes amigo les cuento que tengo un controller de búsqueda, y allí mando los datos a mi vista (
->paginate(100) actualmente muestra 100 registros en la primera hoja, más paginación, en mi vista blade tengo esto:

```
  @foreach($com->obras as $ob)
               
                     
       <td>{{ $ob->fecha}}</td>

  @endforeach
```

luego que hago clic en boton buscar hace la busqueda. El problema es que muestra los registros según el paginate(100) pero yo quiero que no muestre registros antes de hacer la busqueda, es decir esté vacio, lo que realmente quiero es que construya la table después que haga clic en buscar con los datos que arroje la busqueda, en teoría desearia hacer eso:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Alguna idea de como se hace en la vista blade de laravel? tengo laravel 6

Comment: mi pregunta es como se hace esto en laravel: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: yo lo que quiero es que mi formulario de busqueda cuando yo haga clic en buscar, contruya la tabla con los parametros que le pase, ya que ahorita sin buscar me muestra todos los registros pero paginados, espero haberme explicado mejor

Comment: Entonces esto: `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))` no tiene algo que ver en tu duda y lo que deberías considerar es tener tu formulario y el encabezado de la tabla, hacer la búsqueda y si retorna datos entonces poblar la tabla con las filas obtenidas y si no entonces notificar que se carecen de elementos que mostrar

Comment: exacto eso es lo que quiero como hacer que se poblen los datos ese while lo puse a modo de ejemplo que basicamente hace los mismo pero en php, me puedes orientar en donde obtengo informacion de lo que quiero hacer?